# Dividing processes equally among users, linux kernel programming

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks

I want to equally distribute the processes on the CPU to the users.
For example, I have 4 users, user A and B have 2 processes , User B and C have 4 processes , in total there are 10 processes. All users can use 25% on CPU for these processes. I edited a certain part of the sched.c file in the Linux kernel, but there is a part where I am stuck.

What I want to do is suppose we have 4 users for this example, no matter how many processes the users have, they should all use the CPU equally. For example, let's say that user A has 2, user B has 2, user C has 3, user D has 3, and a total of 10 processes. User A and user B will use the CPU at 25% per user and 12.5% per processes. User C and D will use the CPU at 25% per user and 8.5% per processes.

**The CPU should behave equally to all user processes, how can I do this?**

```
asmlinkage void schedule(void)
    {
        struct schedule_data * sched_data;
        struct task_struct *prev, *next, *p;
        struct list_head *tmp;
        int this_cpu, c;
        /* our variables */
        unsigned int rnd;
        unsigned int found = 0;
        gid_t runGid;
        unsigned int sumOfAllFlags = 0;
    
    
    
        spin_lock_prefetch(&runqueue_lock);
    
        BUG_ON(!current->active_mm);
    need_resched_back:
        prev = current;
        this_cpu = prev->processor;
    
        if (unlikely(in_interrupt())) {
            printk("Scheduling in interrupt\n");
            BUG();
        }
    
        release_kernel_lock(prev, this_cpu);
    
        /*
         * 'sched_data' is protected by the fact that we can run
         * only one process per CPU.
         */
        sched_data = & aligned_data[this_cpu].schedule_data;
    
        spin_lock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
    
        /* move an exhausted RR process to be last.. */
        if (unlikely(prev->policy == SCHED_RR))
            if (!prev->counter) 
            {
                prev->counter = NICE_TO_TICKS(prev->nice);
                move_last_runqueue(prev);
            }
    
        switch (prev->state) 
        {
            case TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE:
                if (signal_pending(prev)) 
                {
                    prev->state = TASK_RUNNING;
                    break;
                }
            default:
                del_from_runqueue(prev);
            case TASK_RUNNING:;
        }
        prev->need_resched = 0;
    
        /*
         * this is the scheduler proper:
         */
    
    repeat_schedule:
        /*
         * Default process to select..
         */
        next = idle_task(this_cpu);
        //prev->willBeChoosen = 0; //willBeChoosen of prev process = 0
        if (sched_type == SCHED_DEFAULT) 
        {
    
            // next = idle_task(this_cpu);
            c = -1000;
            list_for_each(tmp, &runqueue_head) 
            {
               p = list_entry(tmp, struct task_struct, run_list);
               if (can_schedule(p, this_cpu)) 
               {
                   int weight = goodness(p, this_cpu, prev->active_mm);
                   if (weight > c)
                       c = weight, next = p;
               }
            } 
    
           /* Do we need to re-calculate counters? */
            if (unlikely(!c)) 
            {
                struct task_struct *p;
    
                spin_unlock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
                read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
    
                for_each_task(p) 
                {
                    p->counter = (p->counter >> 1) + NICE_TO_TICKS(p->nice);
                }
                read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
                spin_lock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
                goto repeat_schedule;
            }
        }
        else if (sched_type == GTICKET)
        {     
    
                current->prevJiffies = jiffies;
    
                // sum of group flags of all processes
                sumOfAllFlags = 0;
    
            // calculate sum of flags of all processes
            // -> are there any unprocessed waiting processes
          
                spin_unlock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
                read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
    
            list_for_each(tmp, &runqueue_head) 
            {           
                p = list_entry(tmp, struct task_struct, run_list);
                //p->willBeChoosen = 0;
                sumOfAllFlags = sumOfAllFlags + p->groupFlag;
            }
    
                read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
                spin_lock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
            
                // Check if all processed
            // If so go to repeat schedule
            // Mark all existing as unprocessed
            
                spin_unlock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
                read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
    
          if (sumOfAllFlags == 0)
            {
             list_for_each(tmp, &runqueue_head)
                {
                    p = list_entry(tmp, struct task_struct, run_list);
                    p->groupFlag = 1;
                }
                // goto repeat_schedule;
          }
    
          read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
          spin_lock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
          
          
        spin_unlock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
          read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
          
          list_for_each(tmp, &runqueue_head)
            {
                p = list_entry(tmp, struct task_struct, run_list);  
    
                if((current->prevJiffies - p->prevJiffies) > 1)
                {   
                    p->counter--;
                }                       
                else if((current->prevJiffies - p->prevJiffies) < 4)
                {
                    p->counter--;
                }   
    
            }
    
          read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
          spin_lock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
          
    
          // Random Selection of next process
            // Random Selection is between 1 and 15
            /*get_random_bytes(&rnd, sizeof(unsigned int));
            if(rnd < 0)
                rnd = rnd*(-1);
            if(maxTicket>0)
            {
                rnd = (rnd % maxTicket);
                rnd++;
            }*/
    
            // if process's ticket is greater or equal to rnd
            // next process <- that process
          
          spin_unlock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
          read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
    
            list_for_each(tmp, &runqueue_head)
            {
                p = list_entry(tmp, struct task_struct, run_list);
    
                if (can_schedule(p, this_cpu)) 
                {          
                    if (p->groupFlag>0)
                    {
                       p->willBeChoosen = 20;
                               runGid = get_gid(p->user->uid);
                       //p->prevJiffies = jiffies;
                       break;
                    }
                }
            }
    
          read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
          spin_lock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
           
          //choosing next process using goodness with the integrated will be chosen variable
          next = idle_task(this_cpu);
          c = -1000;
          
          spin_unlock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
          read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
          
          list_for_each(tmp, &runqueue_head) 
           {
               p = list_entry(tmp, struct task_struct, run_list);
               if (can_schedule(p, this_cpu)) 
               {
                   int weight = goodness(p, this_cpu, prev->active_mm);
                   if (weight > c)
                   {
                       c = weight, next = p;
                   }
              }
           }
    
          read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
          spin_lock_irq(&runqueue_lock);      
        
    
          spin_unlock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
          read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
                                                                
          list_for_each(tmp, &runqueue_head) 
          {         
             p = list_entry(tmp, struct task_struct, run_list);
             p->willBeChoosen = 0;
          }
                                                                
          read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
          spin_lock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
    
          /* Do we need to re-calculate counters? */
          if (unlikely(!c)) 
          {
            struct task_struct *p;
                                                                         
            spin_unlock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
            read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
                                                                         
            for_each_task(p) 
            {
                p->counter = (p->counter >> 1) + NICE_TO_TICKS(p->nice);
                                                                         
            }
            read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
            spin_lock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
            goto repeat_schedule;
          }
    
          // Assign all processes with the same group id as processed
          // So that a group based fair scheduler can be achived
    
          spin_unlock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
            read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
    
            list_for_each(tmp, &runqueue_head)
            {
                p = list_entry(tmp, struct task_struct, run_list);
                
                  if (get_gid(p->user->uid) == runGid)
                        p->groupFlag = 0;
            }
    
            read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
            spin_lock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
    
        }
        
        /*
         * from this point on nothing can prevent us from
         * switching to the next task, save this fact in
         * sched_data.
         */
        sched_data->curr = next;
        task_set_cpu(next, this_cpu);
        spin_unlock_irq(&runqueue_lock);
    
        if (unlikely(prev == next)) 
        {
            /* We won't go through the normal tail, so do this by hand */
            prev->policy &= ~SCHED_YIELD;
            goto same_process;
        }
```

Comment: user A and B have 2 processes , User B and C have 4 processes , in total there are 10 processes. I don't understand why there are 10 totally.

Comment: @tyChen I said the value 10 to give an example. What I want to do is suppose we have 4 users for this example, no matter how many processes the users have, they should all use the CPU equally. For example, let's say that user A has 2, user B has 2, user C has 3, user D has 3, and a total of 10 processes. User A and user B will use the CPU at 25% per user and 12.5% per processes. User C and D will use the CPU at 25% per user and 8.5% per processes.

Comment: doesn't using the limits solve this situation? You can set /etc/security/limits.conf limits. For instance, you can set the maximum CPU time per login and/or the maximum number of processes per login.

Comment: @EdgarCarvalho This is an assignment(homework) given to me and we are asked to solve this assignment in this way.